# Kotlin. Android. Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I ran into a problem with my application. Below I will present you the error and code snippets where there may be a problem. I hope you'll give me a hand!

I provide my error code:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.skreep.starwarsappandroid/com.skreep.starwarsappandroid.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException
```

Shows that the error is in these fragment:

```
 at com.skreep.starwarsappandroid.ui.fragments.home.HomeFragment.setupViewModel(HomeFragment.kt:44)
 at com.skreep.starwarsappandroid.ui.fragments.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:30)
```

And also in MainActivity

```
at com.skreep.starwarsappandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15)
```

You can take a look at my fragment and MainActivity code. I provide it below.
**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        bottomNavigationView()

    }
    private fun bottomNavigationView() {
        val bottom = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigation)
        val controller = findNavController(R.id.fragment)
        bottom.setupWithNavController(controller)
    }

}
```

**Fragment**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel
    private lateinit var adapter: HomeListAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        setupViewModel()
        setupUI()
        setupObservers()

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        return view

    }

    private fun setupViewModel() {
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(
            this,
            HomeViewModelFactory(ApiHelper(RetrofitBuilder.starWarsApi))
        ).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

    }

    private fun setupUI() {
        binding.recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        adapter = HomeListAdapter(arrayListOf())
        binding.recycler.addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(
                binding.recycler.context,
                (binding.recycler.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).orientation
            )
        )
        binding.recycler.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun setupObservers() {
        viewModel.getCharacters().observe(this, Observer {
            it?.let { resource ->
                when (resource.status) {
                    Status.SUCCESS -> {
                        binding.recycler.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        resource.data?.let { users -> retrieveList(users) }
                    }

                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun retrieveList(users: List<Characters>) {
        adapter.apply {
            addUsers(users)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.skreep.starwarsappandroid, PID: 19296
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.skreep.starwarsappandroid/com.skreep.starwarsappandroid.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in com.skreep.starwarsappandroid:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #32 in com.skreep.starwarsappandroid:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in com.skreep.starwarsappandroid:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #32 in com.skreep.starwarsappandroid:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in com.skreep.starwarsappandroid:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras mush have an application by `APPLICATION_KEY`
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:261)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:168)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:137)
        at com.skreep.starwarsappandroid.ui.fragments.home.HomeFragment.setupViewModel(HomeFragment.kt:44)
        at com.skreep.starwarsappandroid.ui.fragments.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:30)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:523)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1374)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2841)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2777)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3020)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:394)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:260)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:295)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:274)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.skreep.starwarsappandroid.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:45)
        at com.skreep.starwarsappandroid.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:39)
        at com.skreep.starwarsappandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7809)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7798)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

ViewModel

```
class HomeViewModel(private val repository: StarWarsRepository) : ViewModel() {

    fun getCharacters() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Resource.loading(data = null))
        try {
            emit(Resource.success(data = repository.getCharacters()))
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            emit(Resource.error(data = null, message = exception.message ?: "Error Occurred!"))
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelFactory

```
class HomeViewModelFactory(private val apiHelper: ApiHelper) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(HomeViewModel::class.java)) {
            return HomeViewModel(StarWarsRepository(apiHelper)) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown class name")
    }

}
```

I would be grateful for any help to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean?

Comment: It looks like error is somewhere in fragment XML.

Comment: added HomeViewModel and HomeViewModelFactory

Comment: I still can't quite reconcile that stack trace with the source, but the first thing I would check is to make sure that the `dependencies` in your app's `build.gradle` are up to date. That specific section was involved in a very recent update, but I can't tell if it was a bug fix, or simply an improvement.

Comment: I should also mention that if you resolve this particular `IllegalStateException`, you're going to get a `NullPointerException` next in that same class, 'cause you're trying to use `binding`/`_binding` before it's assigned. Just a heads up.

Comment: FWIW, I ran a quick test with your setup and up-to-date dependencies, and it gave no such error. Hopefully you just need to update.

Comment: A couple questions, which line is line 15 in MainActivity and are you planning on sharing this viewmodel or is it only for your fragment?